# "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'count'; For input string: \"count\""

Tags: java

I need count users in mysql using spring boot to display a statistic

my code content 3 class and interface :

```java
////////////////interface////////////////////
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>

String count(String name);

////////////////service////////////////////
public String count(String username);

@Override
public String count(String username) {
    return userRepository.count(username);
}

//////////////////iontroller////////////
@GetMapping("/count")
public String count(String username) {
    return userService.count(username);
}
```

result in postman:

```
"message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'count'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"count\""
```

Comment: Q: How many times are you going to (re)declare "count()"?  Q: Where doe you define "count" as a "String" (most of the places above, apparently...) ... and where do you define it as a "Long" (the source of your error)?  Q: In Postman, are you calling `<serviceURL>/count/<user id#>`?

Comment: That looks like you're trying to pass `count` as the value, rather than a number... could you put an example payload of what you're actually sending?

Comment: I wanted to extract statistics from my application, bring out the number of users (after each addition), how to do it with springboot and mysql  ??

Comment: This looks like an almost [exact duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578152/failed-to-convert-from-type-java-lang-string-to-type-java-lang-long-for-valu). That's curious.

Comment: And it got deleted three minutes after I mentioned that. Even more curious.

Comment: u not have another job ??? Mc Emperor or error ?

Answer (score 1):

In the repository you need to use `countBy` clause with searching field name and return long as return type. Assuming in `User` entity `username` is a field.

```
long countByUsername(String username);
```

Comment: same error here , 
I tried as follows:
in Repository 
```   long countByUsername(String name); ```
in Controller 
```   @GetMapping("/count")
    public long count(String name) {
        return userService.countByUsername(name);
    }
 ```
in service 
```  @Override
    public long countByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.countByUsername(username);
    } ```